# Storing files in Mongo's GridFS vs File System

Tags: mongodb, blob

I read the question here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

and this paper:

http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525

where they talk about the pluses and minuses of storing blobs in a DB vs just storing pointers to files on a file system. I have been using mongoDB to store files using GridFS (pymongo driver). Doesn't MongoDB's chunking address some of the issues that RMDBs have in this area? Is it still better in most/some cases to store the file to a file system?